# How can I wait in a function for an event to be raised

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a function `GetLogs` that calls another function `GetHistoricalData`. GetHistoricalData is running in a thread and at the end of it, it fires an event `AsyncLoggingRequestFinished`. What I want is to wait in `GetLogs` for the event to be raised. Here is a code example to make thinks clearer:

```
Private Sub GetLogs
    _historicalLogging = new HistoricalLogging()
    AddHandler _historicalLogging.AsyncLoggingRequestFinished, AddressOf _historicalLogging_AsyncLoggingRequestFinished
    _historicalLogging.GetHistoricalData("LogCategory")
   'I want to wait here and after the event raised, keep going
End Sub

Private Sub _historicalLogging_AsyncLoggingRequestFinished(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AsyncRequestSuccessArgs)
    RemoveHandler _historicalLogging.AsyncLoggingRequestFinished, AddressOf _historicalLogging_AsyncLoggingRequestFinished
    For Each entry in _historicalLogging.Entries
        'DoSomething
    Next
End Sub
```

Note: HistoricalLogging is an object from a DLL. I cant change any code of that object

Comment: which .net framework are you using?

Comment: @Default 4.6.1 and Visual Studio 2013

Comment: If you are using Tasks in your program you might look into [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx). Otherwise I'd guess I'd go for [AutoResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx). Which one would you prefer?

Comment: Instead having `GetLogs` wait for the event to fire, you could have it exit (after saving any required information in class-level variables). Then put the code for whatever you want to do after the event in the event handler, or another Sub called from the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way to do it but it works

```
Private Sub GetLogs()
    _historicalLogging = New HistoricalLogging()
    AddHandler _historicalLogging.AsyncLoggingRequestFinished, AddressOf _historicalLogging_AsyncLoggingRequestFinished
    _historicalLogging.GetHistoricalData("LogCategory")
    'I want to wait here and after the event raised, keep going
    Do Until EventRaisen
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
    EventRaisen = False
    'Code After The Event Has Raisen
End Sub
Dim EventRaisen As Boolean = False
Private Sub _historicalLogging_AsyncLoggingRequestFinished(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AsyncRequestSuccessArgs)
    RemoveHandler _historicalLogging.AsyncLoggingRequestFinished, AddressOf _historicalLogging_AsyncLoggingRequestFinished
    For Each entry In _historicalLogging.Entries            
        EventRaisen = True
        'DoSomething
    Next
End Sub
```